# Bounded gradient in weak $L^1$ implies compactness in $L^1$ (?) Relation to fractional Sobolev compactness.

Tags: compactness, fractional-sobolev-spaces, weak-lp-spaces

Let $u_k$ be a sequence of functions in $C^{\infty}_c(B_1),$ where $B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is the unit ball.

Then, if
$$\sup_{k} \|u_k\|_{L^1(B_1)} < \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \sup_{k} \|\nabla u_k\|_{L^{1,\infty}(B_1)}<\infty,$$
is it true that there is a subsequence converging strongly in some function space?

In the above, the weak-$L^1$ norm of a function $v$ is defined as
$$\|v\|_{L^{1,\infty}(B_1)} = \sup_{t > 0} t \, |\{x \in B_1 \,\colon \, |\nabla v(x)| > t\}|.$$

More concretely, is it true that, up to a subsequence, we have
$$u_k \to u \quad \text{(say) in } L^{1}(B_1)?$$

For instance, this particular result would be true if we had an inequality of the form
$$[u_k]_{W^{s,1}(B_1)} \leq C \|\nabla u_k\|_{L^{1,\infty}(B_1)}$$
for some $s \in (0,1),$ where
$$[v]_{W^{s,1}(B_1)} = \int_{B_1} \int_{B_1} \dfrac{|v(x)-v(y)|}{|x-y|^{n+s}} d x d y$$
is the Gagliardo seminorm.
Indeed, a known compactness result for fractional Sobolev spaces states that
$$\sup_{k}  \|u_k\|_{L^1(B_1)} + [u_k]_{W^{s, 1}(B_1)} < \infty \quad \Rightarrow \quad u_k \to u \text{ in } L^1(B_1) \text{ up to a subsequence.}$$

Is such an inequality available?

Comment: What is $L^{1,\infty}$ ?

Comment: This is the weak-$L^1$ space. I forgot to add the definition of $\|\cdot\|_{L^{1,\infty}}.$

Comment: Reviving this because I’m very curious if anyone knows anything like this!